# Unable to install API 8

Tags: android, installation

I'm having android `API 4` i'm trying to install `API 8` but it's not working I'm getting the install option disabled

I get some errors like this

1. SSL peer shutdown incorrectly
2. connection reset

should I install any tools for installing API 8

Comment: have you tried use `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: @ManjuManu First Update ADT Plugin and then try.

Answer (score 0):

The low version of the Android system can't install the high version application. In a Android app we can define `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"`. The low version API can install in the AndroidManifest.xml file.